# openssl RSA_verify succeeds after the openssl certificate is expired.

Tags: c, openssl, rsa

I created a self signed openssl certificate using the below commads.

- openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 2048
- openssl rsa -in server.key -out server.key
- openssl req -sha256 -new -key server.key -out server.csr -subj '/CN=localhost'
- openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 10 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out
- cat server.crt server.key > cert.pem

Using the cert.pem and RSA_sign function I created a signature after the certificate expired ( after 10 days )

The RSA_verify of the above signature still succeeds. Can you help me with this?

Best regards,
Poornima.M

Answer (score 0):

`RSA_verify()` will verify the signature taking the rsa public key, it does not deal with the public key certificate.

Public key and the key certificate are not the same thing, public key resides in public key certificate. So when you extracted public key from the certificate there only you have to check if its expired or not and avoid using it if its expired

Comment: Thank you very much. We generate the certificate once and using this certificate we sign a signature using RSA_sign and verify using RSA_verify. We need not worry about the validity of the certificate in this case, is that right?

Comment: Ofcourse validity of cert should be checked but RSA_verify wont do it, you have to do it by some other means, try using X509_get_notAfter() to get expiry date of your cert and validate it against current date

Comment: Get that. Thanks for the comment.